# Using Liferay Service with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, soap, wsdl, liferay

I need to retrieve some information from a Liferay server with Javascript.
I build a service in Liferay so I can generate SOAP requests to the wsdl file and retrieve the data I need. That works well with a SOAP client.

What is the easiest way to generate these SOAP requests in Javascript?

I already tried to use the [Javascript SOAP Client](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx) but I always get the error "wsdl is null". According to the developer this happens because the server isn't able to execute ASP.NET webservices.
Does anyone know an easy alternative to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with REST web services, it is the de-facto standard for JS web service clients.

About the format remember that you may go with XML or JSON.